# Adding an array of buttons to a particular subview

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uibutton

I have a subview that is hidden until a user clicks a button (The subview is a UIScrollview).  I'd like to programmatically add a grid of buttons in that view.  I'm not sure how to specify which view the buttons get added to.  I'm trying to follow http://www.raywenderlich.com/130/how-to-write-a-custom-image-picker-like-uiimagepicker

the scrollview is called graphicView

This is what I have

```
 for(int i=0;i<64;i++)
{
UIImage *buttonImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

    [arrayOfThumbnails addObject:buttonImage];  
}



for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfThumbnails.count; ++i) {

    UIImage *thumb = [arrayOfThumbnails objectAtIndex:i];
    UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(column*100+24, row*80+10, 64, 64);
    [button setImage:thumb forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:graphicView
               action:@selector(buttonClicked:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.tag = i;
    [graphicView addSubview:button];

    if (column == 2) {
        column = 0;
        row++;
    } else {
        column++;
    }

}
```

---

This is the only part I'm not using from the tutorial....

> [view setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, (row+1) * 80 + 10)];     self.view
>   = view;

---

Comment: Honestly I don't understand what is you problem. Is your code not working?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You're adding the buttons to graphicView in your for loop, so what's the problem? Is this not working. Also why are you creating an array for your thumbnails when you put the same image at every index?

Comment: I'm using the same image to just test things out.  No, nothing is showing up.  I did create the scrollview in interface builder.

Comment: i'd verify my scrollview was there and sized properly by changing its background color, then i'd print out the values for each button's frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the UIImage is valid by checking the return value from [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]

Check that your NSMutableArray has been initialized

Your for loop looks unusual, try changing to fast enumeration

```
for (UIImage *thumb in arrayOfThumbnails) {
    // UIImage *thumb = [arrayOfThumbnails objectAtIndex:i]; <-- Not needed
    ...
}
```

Is graphicView being added as a subview somewhere?  Set graphicView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor] so you can see at least it's being added.

Comment: My array of images appears to have no items in it?

Comment: Ok, the array is no longer empty and I create the button and print it in the log and it shows <UIButton: 0x828f5f0; frame = (124 330; 64 64); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8286340>>.  Why wouldn't this be visible?  I tried setting opaque to yes and the same thing.

Comment: Check that with fast enumeration that you're not loading the image again from the array.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Break this down into smaller steps to help find the problem.  Try directly adding image to your view controller view to make sure the image is loading properly.  Next, add the image to the button and add the button to the view controller view.